# Recommended books for post degree casual reading

Tags: reference-request

I've recently finished my undergraduate degree in Maths and am looking for books to continue reading in my spare time to keep my interest in the subject.  I'm not looking for any topics in particular - just good reads with thought provoking ideas!

Any recommendations are welcome!

Comment: Though you are interested in any topic, but as a question this is too board. Can you name one or two areas that you are particularly interested with?

Comment: Sorry for the broad question! I was mostly looking for books that other mathematicians have read and would call a "must read"! As far as my interests go, I spent the majority of my time at university focussing on pure maths/analysis and number theory.

Answer (score 5):

I would highly recommend [The Princeton Companion to Mathematics](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8350.html).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation - that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I bought it pretty much on the same background, and every time I open it I always feel like I'd rather sit with a proper text book. Not that it isn't reasonably well-written, especially considering its breadth, but I often feel frustrated when reading about more esoteric topics.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop your knowledge of math I suggest you take the topic that interests you the most. The topic you find you can easily digest and get a good advanced coursework book and read it!

Also the book "How Not to Be Wrong" by Jordan Ellenberg is a classic for aspiring  math students. It answers the age old question many student ask "Why do we need to study this stuff". And its a good casual read.